# Get rows from XML array using OPENXML

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2012, openxml, sql-server-openxml

I have following XML:

```
<root>
  <fields>
    <field>Some Name</field>
    <field>Another Name</field>
  </fields>
</root>
```

As the result I would like to have:

```
Some Name
Another Name
```

To achieve that I am trying to execute following query:

```
DECLARE @XML XML = N'
<root>
  <fields>
    <field>Some Name</field>
    <field>Another Name</field>
  </fields>
</root>';


DECLARE @idoc INT;
EXEC sys.sp_xml_preparedocument @idoc OUTPUT, @XML;
SELECT  *
FROM    OPENXML(@idoc, '/root/fields',2)
WITH (Name VARCHAR(300)  './field');
EXEC sys.sp_xml_removedocument @idoc;
```

But I am getting only the first record...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
DECLARE @XML XML = N'
<root>
  <fields>
    <field>Some Name</field>
    <field>Another Name</field>
  </fields>
</root>';

-- XQuery
SELECT t.c.value('(./text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(300)')
FROM @XML.nodes('/root/fields/field') t(c)

-- OpenXML
DECLARE @idoc INT
EXEC sys.sp_xml_preparedocument @idoc OUTPUT, @XML

SELECT *
FROM OPENXML(@idoc, '/root/fields/*',2) WITH (Name VARCHAR(300) '.')

EXEC sys.sp_xml_removedocument @idoc
```